# String extraction from iterating and mixed lines in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a dataset as below;

```
"birth_date_1:25        birth_date_2:august     birth_date_3:1945    birth_place_1:france   death_date:<none>   "
"birth_date_1:14        birth_date_2:june       birth_date_3:1995   birth_place_1:dv≈Ør     birth_place_2:kr√°lov√©     birth_place_3:nad       birth_place_4:labem     birth_place_5:,     birth_place_6:czech     birth_place_7:republic  "
"birth_date_1:21        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1869   birth_place_1:blackburn     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:england   death_date_1:12     death_date_2:march      death_date_3:1917   "
"birth_date_1:07        birth_date_2:july       birth_date_3:1979   birth_place_1:ghana     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:accra "
"birth_date_1:27        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1979   birth_place_1:durban        birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:south     birth_place_4:africa    "
"birth_date_1:1989  birth_place_1:lima      birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:peru  "
"birth_date_1:5     birth_date_2:september      birth_date_3:1980   birth_place_1:angola    death_date:<none>   "
"birth_date_1:1     birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1856   birth_place_1:hampstead     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:london    death_date_1:14     death_date_2:august     death_date_3:1905   "
"birth_date_1:28        birth_date_2:december       birth_date_3:1954   birth_place_1:hickory       birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:north     birth_place_4:carolina  death_date:<none>   "
"birth_date:<none>  "
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place:<none>  death_date:<none>   "
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place_1:belfast       birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:northern      birth_place_4:ireland   "
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place:<none>  death_date:<none>   "
"birth_date_1:28        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1891   birth_place_1:carberry      birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:manitoba  death_date_1:20     death_date_2:september      death_date_3:1968   "
"birth_date_1:4     birth_date_2:november       birth_date_3:1993   birth_place_1:portim√£o     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:portugal  "
```

Within these dataset I am trying to extract information as below;

```
25.08.1945 \t France \t NA
14.06.1995 \t Dvůr Králové nad Labem,Czech Republic \t 
21.02.1896 \t Blackburn,England \t 12.03.1917
.
.
.
1989 \t Lima,Peru \t NA
.
.
.
NA \t NA \t NA
NA \t NA \t NA
NA \t Belfast, Northern Ireland \t NA
.
.
04.11.1993 \t Portimeo,Portugal \t NA
```

I wrote below code to achieve this however because of the several scenarios I will encounter in my dataset such as birth_date_1 information can be null, a month name or a year, the loop below I came up with feels like is going to fail somewhere and won't be feasible.

```
    outputfile = open('ornek_box_seperated_update.csv','w',encoding="utf-8")
    inputfile = open('ornek_box_seperated.csv','r',encoding="utf-8")
    import numpy as np

    birthDatePlace = [[ np.nan for i in range(9) ] for j in range(20000)]

    for line in inputfile:
        d = line.split(":")
        print(d)
        d = line.split(d)
        d = "\t".join(d)
        print(d)
        if(d[1]<40 and d[1]>0):
            birthDatePlace[line,1] = d[1]
        elif(d[1]<2020):
            birthDatePlace[line,3] = d[1]
        if(d[1]<40 and d[1]>0 and isinstance(d[3])==str):
            birthDatePlace[line,2] = d[3]
        elif(d[1]<2020 and isinstance(d[3])==int):
            birthDatePlace[line,4] = d[3]

        # this code planned to continue from here until cover the all birth place and death date information in required format

        outputfile.write(d)
        outputfile.write('\n')
    outputfile.close()
```

I appreciate any help you can provide. I am kinda newbie in python and especially in regex or string extraction methodologies.

Thank you in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid code breakages, it would be better to have explicit checks. Please check the code below. I have parsed the information and stored it in an a class object. The class has some helper functions to modify the parsed data.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Class for storing parsed information
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, birth_date_1, birth_date_2, birth_date_3, birth_place, death_date_1, death_date_2, death_date_3):
        if not (birth_date_1 or birth_date_2 or birth_date_3):
            self.birth_date = "NA"
        else:
            if birth_date_2 and birth_date_2.isalpha():
                birth_date_2 = self.month_string_to_number(birth_date_2)
            self.birth_date = '.'.join([birth_date_1, birth_date_2, birth_date_3]).strip(".")

        self.birth_place = birth_place if birth_place.strip(",") else "NA"

        if not (death_date_1 or death_date_2 or death_date_3):
            self.death_date = "NA"
        else:
            if death_date_2 and death_date_2.isalpha():
                death_date_2 = self.month_string_to_number(death_date_2)
            self.death_date = '.'.join([death_date_1, death_date_2, death_date_3]).strip(".")

        self.sanitize()

    def print_req_format(self):
        print '\t'.join([self.birth_date, self.birth_place, self.death_date])

    def sanitize(self):
        if "<none>" in self.birth_date:
            self.birth_date = "NA"
        if "<none>" in self.birth_place:
            self.birth_place = "NA"
        if "<none>" in self.death_date:
            self.death_date = "NA"

    def month_string_to_number(self, month):
        m = {
            'jan': 1,
            'feb': 2,
            'mar': 3,
            'apr': 4,
            'may': 5,
            'jun': 6,
            'jul': 7,
            'aug': 8,
            'sep': 9,
            'oct': 10,
            'nov': 11,
            'dec': 12
        }
        s = month.strip()[:3].lower()

        try:
            out = m[s]
            return str(out)
        except:
            return ""

dataset = [
"birth_date_1:25        birth_date_2:august     birth_date_3:1945    birth_place_1:france   death_date:<none>",
"birth_date_1:14        birth_date_2:june       birth_date_3:1995   birth_place_1:dv≈Ør     birth_place_2:kr√°lov√©     birth_place_3:nad       birth_place_4:labem     birth_place_5:,     birth_place_6:czech     birth_place_7:republic",
"birth_date_1:21        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1869   birth_place_1:blackburn     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:england   death_date_1:12     death_date_2:march      death_date_3:1917",
"birth_date_1:07        birth_date_2:july       birth_date_3:1979   birth_place_1:ghana     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:accra",
"birth_date_1:27        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1979   birth_place_1:durban        birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:south     birth_place_4:africa",
"birth_date_1:1989  birth_place_1:lima      birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:peru",
"birth_date_1:5     birth_date_2:september      birth_date_3:1980   birth_place_1:angola    death_date:<none>",
"birth_date_1:1     birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1856   birth_place_1:hampstead     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:london    death_date_1:14     death_date_2:august     death_date_3:1905",
"birth_date_1:28        birth_date_2:december       birth_date_3:1954   birth_place_1:hickory       birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:north     birth_place_4:carolina  death_date:<none>",
"birth_date:<none>",
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place:<none>  death_date:<none>",
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place_1:belfast       birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:northern      birth_place_4:ireland",
"birth_date:<none>  birth_place:<none>  death_date:<none>",
"birth_date_1:28        birth_date_2:february       birth_date_3:1891   birth_place_1:carberry      birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:manitoba  death_date_1:20     death_date_2:september      death_date_3:1968",
"birth_date_1:4     birth_date_2:november       birth_date_3:1993   birth_place_1:portim√£o     birth_place_2:,     birth_place_3:portugal",
]

for line in dataset:
    split_data_line = line.split()
    birth_date_1 = birth_date_2 = birth_date_3 = birth_place = death_date_1 = death_date_2 = death_date_3 = ""
    for data in split_data_line:
        split_data = data.split(":")
        if len(split_data) < 2:
            continue

        val = split_data[1]
        if data.startswith("birth_date_1"):
            birth_date_1 = val
        elif data.startswith("birth_date_2"):
            birth_date_2 = val
        elif data.startswith("birth_date_3"):
            birth_date_3 = val
        elif data.startswith("birth_place"):
            if not birth_place or val == ",":
                birth_place += val
            else:
                birth_place += " " + val
        elif data.startswith("death_date_1"):
            death_date_1 = val
        elif data.startswith("death_date_2"):
            death_date_2 = val
        elif data.startswith("death_date_3"):
            death_date_3 = val

    info = Info(birth_date_1, birth_date_2, birth_date_3, birth_place, death_date_1, death_date_2, death_date_3)
    info.print_req_format()
```

The output for this code according to your data provided is:

```
25.8.1945   france  NA
14.6.1995   dv≈Ør kr√°lov√© nad labem, czech republic   NA
21.2.1869   blackburn, england  12.3.1917
07.7.1979   ghana, accra    NA
27.2.1979   durban, south africa    NA
1989    lima, peru  NA
5.9.1980    angola  NA
1.2.1856    hampstead, london   14.8.1905
28.12.1954  hickory, north carolina NA
NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA
NA  belfast, northern ireland   NA
NA  NA  NA
28.2.1891   carberry, manitoba  20.9.1968
4.11.1993   portim√£o, portugal NA
```

The code is simple enough to understand. Hope this works for you. Cheers.

Comment: `bool('123'.isalpha)`?

Comment: @G_M nice catch. sorry it was a function call. edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

FIELDNAMES = ('birth_date', 'birth_place', 'death_date')

with open('infile', 'r') as f:
    result = []
    for line in f:
        record = {k: '' for k in FIELDNAMES}
        for kv in line.strip('" \n').split():
            k, v = kv.split(':')
            if v == '<none>':
                continue
            key = k.rstrip('_0123456789')
            value = ' ' + v if record[key] and v != ',' else v
            record[key] += value
        result.append(record)

with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(result)
```

`'outfile.csv'`:

```
birth_date,birth_place,death_date
25 august 1945,france,
14 june 1995,"dv≈Ør kr√°lov√© nad labem, czech republic",
21 february 1869,"blackburn, england",12 march 1917
07 july 1979,"ghana, accra",
27 february 1979,"durban, south africa",
1989,"lima, peru",
5 september 1980,angola,
1 february 1856,"hampstead, london",14 august 1905
28 december 1954,"hickory, north carolina",
,,
,,
,"belfast, northern ireland",
,,
28 february 1891,"carberry, manitoba",20 september 1968
4 november 1993,"portim√£o, portugal",
```